# Cannot see inapp-purchase item

Tags: ios, xcode

In to Capabilities tap of Xcode, I didn't see the Inapp-Purchase. So that, I cannot open it. Please help me show it.I use Xcode 7.3. Please view image for detail:
[image]

Comment: I think this link will help you https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2259/_index.html

Comment: My problem is cannot see Inapp-Purchase item to open it :(

Answer (score 0):

It's not good practice, but I found the way to fix my problem. The problem is my apple ID account doesn't have inapp-purchase. So I change setting as image below, it'll show inapp-purchase for me. Hope this will help someone whose face same problem as mine.
[image]